# subscript or superscript causes chemical bond vertical shift

Tags: chemfig

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
     $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {CH=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
     $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {CH_2=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
     $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {H_2C=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
     $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {C_4H_2=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
\end{document}
```

As you can see, chemical bond in formula with subscript vertical shift are lower, I know it's 'chemfig' macro's algorithm consequence. But I wonder how to disable this shift? 
Thanks to answer.

[image]

---

UPDATE:
I have got a tex.cls which has lots of \NewDocumentCommand which satisfy customized feature. So I can't change macro. And because of common NewDocumentCommand, I have to ensure atom sep & bond offset & italics

It's a eg:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myChem}{m}{
   $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig #1\par
}
```

So far, I've try \vphantom and chemskipalign macro, but not success to vertical shift problem. May be my usage of this macro is wrong. Hope for answer and thanks to 'andselisk' .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {CH=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {CH_2=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {H_2C=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {C_4H_2=C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig { CH= \chemskipalign C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig { CH_2= \chemskipalign C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {H_2C=\chemskipalign C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par
    \item  $\rm \setatomsep{2em}\setbondoffset{0pt}\chemfig {C_4H_2=\chemskipalign. C}(CH_3)OCH_3$\par

    \chemfig{A-B-C-D}\qquad \chemfig{E-F-G-H}\par
    \chemfig{A^1-B-C-D}\qquad \chemfig{E_1-F-G-H}\par
    \chemfig{\vphantom{C}A^1-B-C-D}\qquad \chemfig{\vphantom{G}E_1-F-G-H}\par
    \chemfig{A^1-B-{\vphantom{A^1}C}-D}\qquad \chemfig{E_1-F-{\vphantom{E_1}G}-H}\par
    \chemfig{A^1-\chemskipalign B-C-D}\qquad \chemfig{E_1-\chemskipalign F-G-H}\par
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: And I can't to change macro to mhchem~

Comment: This is a well-documented behavior, see [chemfig's manual, section 4. Vertical Alignment](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf#page=28). tl:dr is you want to use `\chemskipalign` macro. Also, your code looks weird to me in a sense that there is no need to use either math mode, or `\rm`, or declare the same settings again on each line.

Comment: Thanks to  andselisk,  I've update my question description.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `chemfig` is not the best for this kind of formulas. It's easier with `chemformula`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\setchemformula{bond-length=1em}

\begin{document}

\ch{CH=C(CH3)OCH3}\par
\ch{CH2=C(CH3)OCH3}\par
\ch{H2C=C(CH3)OCH3}\par
\ch{C4H2=C(CH3)OCH3}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]